# AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, ios5, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

It's day three and I still can't get playback. I've been following the few tutorials on AVAudioPlayer/AVAudioRecorder. Using NSFileManager it looks like a file is created, but no dice still on that playback.

RecorderViewController.m

```
//  RecorderViewController.m
//  AudioTest
//

#import "RecorderViewController.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RecorderViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecorderViewController

@synthesize userIsRecording, filePath, activityView, recordButton, playButton, recorder;

/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

+ (CGRect)makeCGRectWithCenter:(CGPoint)center width:(float)width height:(float)height 
{
    return CGRectMake(center.x-width/2, center.y-height/2, width, height);
}

#pragma mark - Preparation
- (void)loadView 
{
    // RECORD BUTTON
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    self.recordButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.recordButton.frame = [[self class] makeCGRectWithCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 100) width:150 height:50];
    [self.recordButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // PLAY BUTTON
    self.playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.playButton.frame = [[self class] makeCGRectWithCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 200) width:150 height:50];
    [self.playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // RETURN BUTTON
    UIButton *returnButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    returnButton.frame = [[self class] makeCGRectWithCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 300) width:150 height:50];
    [returnButton setTitle:@"Return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // ACTIVITY
    self.activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.activityView.frame = [[self class] makeCGRectWithCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 50) width:100 height:100];

    [self.view addSubview:self.recordButton];
    [self.view addSubview:self.playButton];
    [self.view addSubview:returnButton];
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityView];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"View did load");
    filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp2.caf"]];

    // Setup AudioSession
    AVAudioSession *avSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [avSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:NULL];
    [avSession setActive:YES error: NULL];
    self.playButton.hidden = YES;
}


#pragma mark - Button Actions

- (void)dismissPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Button class dismissed self");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Sender is:%@", [sender class]);
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)stopPressed {
    NSLog(@"Stop Pressed");
    [self.recordButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.userIsRecording = NO;
    self.playButton.hidden = NO;
    self.playButton.enabled = YES;
    [self.activityView stopAnimating];

    //
}

- (void)recordPressed
{
    if (self.userIsRecording) {
        [self stopPressed];
    }
    else {
        self.userIsRecording = YES;
        self.playButton.enabled = NO;
        self.playButton.hidden = YES;
        [self.recordButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.activityView startAnimating];

        NSDictionary *recorderSettings = 
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey, 
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey, nil];

        // Clean temp file
        NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[self.filePath path] error:NULL];

        // Record
        NSError *error = [NSError alloc];
        self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:self.filePath settings:recorderSettings error:&error];

        [recorder setDelegate:self];
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        if (![recorder record]) {
            NSLog(@"Recorder FAIL %@", error );
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Recording at %@", [self.filePath absoluteString]);
        }
    }
}

- (void)playPressed
{
    NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:[self.filePath path]]) {
        NSLog(@"File exists at:%@", [self.filePath path]);
        NSDictionary *attr = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[self.filePath path] error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"File attrs:%@", [attr description]);
    }


    else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: No file exists at:%@", [self.filePath path]);
    }

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.filePath] error: &error];

    [player setDelegate:self];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Player initialization Error: %@", error);
    }

    if (!player) {
        NSLog(@"Player is null!");
    }
    [player prepareToPlay];
    if (![player play]) {
        NSLog(@"Play Error: %@", error);
    }
}

#pragma mark - Lifecycle


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    NSLog(@"View did unload");
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: I see in your `- (void)playPressed` that you call `[player prepareToPlay]`, but I don't actually see you telling it to play. prepareToPlay just makes it ready. Maybe I'm missing it in your code or you didn't post all of it. Just my quick glancing observation.

Comment: It's  bit hidden in the logic:

    `if (![player play]) {
        NSLog(@"Play Error: %@", error);
    }`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little new to programming, but isn't that if statement just saying "If player isn't playing, then show this error message"? You would still have to say `[player play];` in there after `[player prepareToPlay]`.

Comment: If you're new to programming then try sample code [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) and modify it to your needs.

Comment: Have you added the AVFoundation framework to your project and imported to your .h file? `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Answer (score 0):

```
[player prepareToPlay];
if (![player play]) {
    NSLog(@"Play Error: %@", error);
}
```

You play the file right after you "prepare to play". The buffer maybe it's not still ready at that moment. Make this test. Declare `AVAudioPlayer *player` as global. Remove `if (![player play])...` from  `- (void)playPressed`. Now create  a new method that will be invoked on other button press. Press your play button, wait a couple of seconds, and press the other button.